# Safari Extension Sending a Message To an App

Tags: macos, safari, safari-extension, browser-extension

I'm new in making browser extensions. I need to make an extension for Safari capable of launching or sending a message to an existing app on user machine. I want to do this in Mac platform. I want to know is it possible? and if it is possible can anyone provide a sample code or a way of how can it be done?

Regards

Comment: have you did anything to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are at least a couple ways a Safari extension can communicate with the outside world. Probably the cleanest is for your extension to open a connection to a [WebSocket](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WebSocket) server running on the local machine.

```
// Inside your extension's master or local .js
WebSocket ws = new WebSocket("ws://localhost/mywebserver");
ws.onopen = function () {
    ws.send("Message to outside world");
};
```

This server could be integrated into your application using a library like [libwebsockets](http://git.warmcat.com/cgi-bin/cgit/libwebsockets/), [jWebSocket](http://jwebsocket.org/), or [Socket.IO](http://socket.io/).